# Google Analytics: Event does not appear are being set up

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Bear with me, because I'm relatively new to using GA and the people who set it up have either left or don't know how to use it. So there could be a deeper problem...

I'm trying to add an event via GTM, but it doesn't appear in my event list on GA. Everything, so far as I can tell, is set up correctly.

1. Do events not appear until they've been triggered? The product gets deployed to customers on a set-basis so there'll be a delay before the trigger is in the product
2. I chose the trigger as `Click Classes` and just added a class to the button. Is this enough to trigger the event?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your GTM settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you set up event tags in GTM that fires after a condition (like your Click Class) is triggered. **Only after then**, the event will get sent to Google Analytics and appear in your Events and Realtime reports.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm after deployment that the event doesn't appear in your events list until it has been fired.